# Unit test a Flask session - cannot reproduce failure with session_transaction

Tags: flask, python-unittest

I am testing a Flask application (Flask 0.9), and in particular I have a session fixture that I would like to run in the documented-way, being something like this (as I understand it):

```
from flask import Flask, session
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def m():
    logging.error(session) # expect {'x': 1}
    return ""

with app.test_request_context() as trc:
  with app.test_client() as c:
    with c.session_transaction() as sess:
      sess['x'] = 1
    c.post()
```

This works as expected, with the output being something like this:

```
ERROR:root:<SecureCookieSession {'x': 1}>
```

Unfortunately I am encountering an unexpected result where the session data is not set in the endpoint function, i.e. the output is something like this:

```
ERROR:root:<SecureCookieSession {}>
```

This issue exhibits only when run from my unit testing framework. As it stands, I am unable to reproduce this problem with a degenerate case, though I have made a fairly substantial effort [with a gist of some of this effort here](https://gist.github.com/brianmhunt/5570166). The salient points being that I have included `itsdangerous` and `Google App Engine testbed`, expecting maybe one of them to have been the cause.

On my own system I have gone further than the *gist*, and almost completely replicated my unit test framework trying to isolate this. Likewise, I have removed ever-increasing amounts of relevant code from my testing framework. To the point, I am unable to think of differences between the degenerate case and my stripped-down framework that could influence the outcome. I have traversed the `c.post()` call in pdb to try eek out the cause of this malignity, but have yet to glean any useful insight.

Which is all to say, I would be grateful for a little direction or suggestion as to where the issue may lie. What could possibly be influencing the Werkzeug context in such a way that the `session_transaction` is not being honoured?

Comment: I know it's been a year, but I'm running into this problem myself. Were you ever able to figure this out? According to what I've read online and in the docs, this should work perfectly. But it doesn't.

Comment: @IanHunter Have a look at my answer, below. It might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
# Code that modifies the current `session`; we must be in a test context already.
headers = {}
with self.client.session_transaction():
    # Get the cookie that is sent to the browser to establish a connection
    # via a fake request.
    response = make_response()
    self.app.session_interface.save_session(self.app, session, response)
    headers['Cookie'] = response.headers.get('Set-Cookie', '')
self.client.post(..., headers=headers)  # also works for .get, .put, etc.
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was restricting cookies to a specific domain automatically by loading a configuration file. By updating the configuration on-the-fly, I was able to get cookies to work while unit testing. Setting the `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` property to `None`, all domains (namely localhost) were able to set sessions.

```
app.config.update(                                                     
    SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None                                                
)
```

You may want to fiddle around with the configuration settings described under [Configuration Handling](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/#configuration-basics) in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to resurrect an old question, but I believe that I figured out the solution to this issue. For testing, try setting your server name to `localhost`:

```
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'localhost'
```

I was originally using Brian's hack, but this solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Without a testcase that actually fails it's hard to say much anything. All I can think of is that the `TestClient` instance you're using the make the request is different from the one you use to set up the session. E.g. you could make the gist fail as expected with this:

```
with self.app.test_client() as c:
    with c.session_transaction() as sess:
        sess['d'] = 1
    self.client.post()
```

But as this isn't the case here or the gist, go figure.

Comment: Thanks. I'm having a little trouble understanding what you are trying to add here, Tommi. If you're noting that the problem is hard, I certainly agree –– hence the bounty! ;)

Comment: As I see it the main reason it's hard is because the code you posted *doesn't fail* as described. So given working code all I can do is make an educated guess for how to make it fail like you described, and the sample I posted seems as good a way as any. Just don't do that in the real code and you should be closer to getting something working.